# Validate the URL in Link href for CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I need to validate and allow only few URLs to be added to editor. Below is the code I used onOK. It validates and gives alert for URLs other than google or yahoo but on success (when I give google) case the URL does not appear in CKeditor.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event
    // data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
if (dialogName == 'link') {
dialogDefinition.onOk = function() {
        var data = {}, editor = this.getParentEditor(),attributes = {};
        this.commitContent(data);

        if (data.type == 'url') {
            var patt = /google|yahoo/;
            if(!patt.test(data.url.url)) {
                alert("Invalid URL");
                return false;
            }
           else {
                 return true;
           }


        }


    };
}
});
```

Comment: Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Resolved this use: onOk && onOk.apply(this, e);
     return true;

Comment: Do you have your solution that you can share - post it as your own answer so people can vote it up.  I am working on a similar issue.  so a common approach would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to declare "defaultOnOk" variable and add "defaultOnOk.apply(this, ev);" before "return true" statement.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
// Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
let dialogName = ev.data.name;
let dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
if (dialogName == 'link') {
    let defaultOnOk = dialogDefinition.onOk;
    dialogDefinition.onOk = function () {            
        let data = {};
        this.commitContent(data);
        if (data.type == 'url') {
            let patt = /google|yahoo/;
            if (!patt.test(data.url.url)) {
                alert("Invalid URL");
                return false;
            }
            else { 
                defaultOnOk.apply(this, ev);
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

});