# How can I validate links with CKEditor using regex?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm working on a cms that uses CKEditor and I want to validate links using regex. There was a similar question asked and answered 7 years ago ([Validate the URL in Link href for CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066690/validate-the-url-in-link-href-for-ckeditor)) but when I try this, I get an error. I'm not sure whether this is because CKEditor has moved on since then or because my setup is different. I'm using the setup as outlined here (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/quick-start-other.html#building-the-editor-from-source) to better understand how CKEditor works.

As described in the link above my setup is as follows:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Link, Essentials, Paragraph, Bold, Italic, Alignment  ],
        toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'alignment' ],
        link: {
            decorators: {
                openInNewTab: {
                    mode: 'manual',
                    label: 'Open in a new tab',
                    defaultValue: true,         // This option will be selected by default.
                    attributes: {
                        target: '_blank',
                        rel: 'noopener noreferrer'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error.stack );
    } );
```

I then have:

```
ClassicEditor.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    console.log("Test")
});
```

but get the error: "ClassicEditor.on is not a function"

if I instead use:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    console.log("Test")
});
```

the error is CKEDITOR is not defined